# How to set selected_key in Rails grouped_options_for_select?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I have this for my dropdown:

`<%= select_tag 'daily_order[kitchen_id]', grouped_options_for_select(Kitchen.for_normal_and_atworld_kitchens_select, selected_key = :id, options = {}), class: "form-control", onchange: "kitchen_change()" %>`

But the `selected_key` is not working when I passed the `:id`.

When I hard coded it like this:

`<%= select_tag 'daily_order[kitchen_id]', grouped_options_for_select(Kitchen.for_normal_and_atworld_kitchens_select, selected_key = 5, options = {}), class: "form-control", onchange: "kitchen_change()" %>`

It's working fine.

My Kitchen model:

```
def self.for_normal_and_atworld_kitchens_select
    {
      'Normal Kitchens' => where(special_kitchen: false, atworld: false).where.not(id: @exclude_kitchens).map {|x| [x.name, x.id]},
      'Around The World Kitchens' => where(special_kitchen: false, atworld: true).where.not(id: @exclude_kitchens).map {|x| [x.name, x.id]}
    }
  end
```

What should I do now to make this [grouped_options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select) selected_key working?

**Note**:

`@exclude_kitchens` is an array of kitchen IDs like [1, 2, 3]. It's returning the correct output and working fine elsewhere inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the symbol `:id` supposed to represent? You have to pass one or more values to be selected. Take a look at the [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select).

You need to get a copy of the ID dynamically somehow, e.g. `@exclude_kitchens.first` or whatever makes sense.